# Solving issue with animation.artistanimation when it displays only one picture

Tags: python, animation

I'm working on a project where I need to do an animation. I worked on a 2D game of life and it worked perfectly. I'm now doing something similar with voxels (in 3D). I keep the same argument for the function but it only shows one image which overlays all the images from the list even if I use `blit = False` or `blit = True`. Here is the code and the result:

```
def animation_matplotlib(Universe, N):
    ims = []
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel("y")
    ax.set_zlabel("z")
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.set_facecolor('black')
    images = []
    liste_images = [Universe]
    for k in range(N):
        avance_vaisseau(Universe)
        U=deepcopy(Universe)
        liste_images.append(U)
    for imgNum in range(len(liste_images)):
        U=liste_images[imgNum][0]
        C=liste_images[imgNum][2]
        img = ax.voxels(U, facecolors=C , shade=False)
        t = ax.annotate(imgNum, (1, 1))
        images.append([img])

    anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(
        fig, images, interval=200, blit=False, repeat_delay=1000)
    plt.show()


Universe=generate_universe_3d(10,0.01)
implantation_vaisseau(1,1,1,10,Universe)
animation_matplotlib(Universe,20)
```

`avance_vaisseau` modificate the universe to the next step.
`U` is the 3d array with the state of each voxels.
`C` is the 3d array with the color of each voxels.

When I run this program 'with the hand', using alternately `avance_vaisseau` and `affichage_universe` which display the universe, I don't have any problems.

[image: animation]

Red denotes the trajectory of the spaceship (vaisseau), in yellow are the stars and in green is the spaceship on a star.

It kind of works but it is not an animation where you see the spaceship moving.

To make it easier for you, look at the following code which don't need any context. I have an error in matplotlib files, maybe `ax.voxels` and `aniamtion.artistanimation` are not working togather, what could be the solution
?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import animation
U1=np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,1]]])
C1=np.array([[['','',''],['','',''],['','','']],[['','',''],['','',''],['','','']],[['','',''],['','',''],['','','c']]])
U2=np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]]])
C2=np.array([[['','',''],['','',''],['','','']],[['','',''],['','',''],['','','']],[['','',''],['','','c'],['','','']]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_facecolor('black')

L=[ax.voxels(U1, facecolors=C1 , shade=False),ax.voxels(U2, facecolors=C2 , shade=False)]
anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, L, interval=200, blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)
plt.show()
```

The error:

```
$ "D:/Program Files (x86)/Anaconda/python.exe" "d:/Users/Seb/Desktop/Coding Wee
k/space_exploration/projet_3D/test_animation.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 196, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 951, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1525, in _init_draw
    artist.set_visible(False)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_visible'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 196, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1271, in _handle_resize
    self._init_draw()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1525, in _init_draw
    artist.set_visible(False)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_visible'
```

**As you can see both voxels are showed togather instead of seeing one after an other.**

[image]